# Designing a Minecraft Redstone Sorter where 64 items every second

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

Problem Currently, I am playing on a server where hoppers transport items at the rate of 64 items a second, and this has proved very difficult to build a sorter for. I'm not at all proficient in Redstone building but have tried building basic sorters and ones that I have found on YouTube and I haven't gotten anything to work. Solution Hopefully one of you is really good at Redstone and can help me design a sorter that can work under these conditions. (I need the sorter that can sort items while I AFK kill witches with a looting 47 sword

P.S. most of the problem is with the sorter itself because no items will stay in the sorter hopper (bc the whole stack goes into the chest so the hopper doesn't have anything to go off of to sort) so any solution to that would be helpful as well.

Comment: Blocks despawn every 35 seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]
Untested - I don't have access to a server with this sort of behavior - but it has a good chance to work - with one big disadvantage of lots of items being "stuck in the system". Precisely, 14 stacks and 37 items. Although with a Looting 47 sword, obtaining enough items to fill the sorters shouldn't be a big problem.

The left side is a standard overflow-proof sorter - the only difference is the lower hopper is nearly full.

The right-side is a 1-tileable auto-dropper that only activates when the dropper is completely full (signal strength 15). The right barrel is empty, so its comparator will give out signal strength 0 as long as the comparator from the dropper doesn't provide signal strength 15. If that happens, the signal strength 15 overrides the state of the empty barrel and the bottom comparator activates the observer clock. This clock then ejects a couple (in my tests - 4) items from the dropper, dropping the signal level below 15 and deactivating the observer clock.

This makes room for 4 items in the dropper - and so it makes the lockable hopper of the sorter able to insert 4 items into the dropper, and pull 4 items from the filter hopper.

And so, at no point is there enough room "downstream" for any of the hoppers to push all 64 items at once, so they will trickle at most at the speed the auto-dropper is clocked.

The barrel below the dropper (one the dropper is pointed into) is there to provide a buffer between the dropper and the output hopper (at the bottom) - otherwise the output hopper would empty the dropper really fast and the whole system would break promptly.

Note: the system uses normal ice for the item iceway, and as such puts restrictions on artificial lighting (daylight OK), or the ice would melt - the ice can't be exposed to light in excess of 10 from any side; it's necessary for the system to be 1-tileable. Ice, being a transparent block, will allow the dropper to be QC-powered but won't activate neighboring ice blocks, not providing QC power to neighbor slice droppers. Opaque blocks like packed ice and blue ice would make three neighboring droppers fire all at once, and eventually break the sorter.

Comment: Hello SF. one thign i forgot to mention is that all items despawn after 30 seconds once dropped!

Comment: @EnVy Well, you can't let them stay "out in the open" on the iceway longer than that then. If you eject them into the water stream over the sorters using a dropper on a standard 4gt clock (like in typical auto-dropper) they won't overwhelm these sorters.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I can see that you are very good at redstone! DO you mind helping me out with my other problem?

Comment: @EnVy Sorry but piston doors are one domain where I'm really poor.